# How to Include total in pandas groupy summary?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm investigating the effect of a categorical variable to other variables in my DataFrame like this:

```
df.groupby("my_categorical_variable").my_other_variable.describe()
```

This gives me means, medians etc. **for each group**.

I also want to get the same summaries **over all rows**, without grouping. For this I do:

```
df.my_other_variable.describe()
```

Can I somehow **combine these two steps**? Eg. can I force `groupby` operator to treat all rows combined as a group?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
pd.concat([df.groupby('my_categorial_variable').my_other_variable.describe(),
           df.describe().T])
```